# dacpac to dacpac comparision and deployment to DB issues?

Tags: dacpac

A similar question about comparison of TEST DACPAC (READY) <=> Production DACPAC with intent of deployment to Production DB Server on SQL Server forums two years ago.

And apparently it was suggested by someone from MS, it is NOT recommended. IT this still relevant? We were hoping to automate our deployments, to achieve continuous build and deployment using DACPAC comparisons.

If you think it is not recommended to use DACPAC, then please provide reason why? and what would you suggest instead?

URL Link to Original SQL Forum question here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a1e5fb60-3283-4acc-b793-cb28e327dd39/using-dacpac-files-in-an-integrated-deployment-process?forum=ssdt

Comment: Why do you want to compare dacpac to dacpac? The normal thing is to have one dacpac that you compare to your dev server, QA, Prod etc so the schema's are all the same

Comment: THanks @EdElliott, that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing dacpac to dacpac is okay, but more things can go wrong when doing this.  For example, the target platform of the "production dacpac" could be different from the actual platform of your production database, which could result in the generated script containing T-SQL that doesn't work on your production server. Or the database options specified in the "production dacpac" may not match the actual database options of your production database, which can again result in the generated script containing T-SQL that won't work on your production database.

Worst of all, the "production dacpac" might not be equivalent to the production database -- i.e. some objects can exist in the production database that aren't in the "production dacpac" or vice-versa -- which could result in unintended side effects like schema or data loss.

This is why, in general, we recommend deploying or generating a deployment script by using the production database as the target directly instead of dacpac to dacpac comparison.

Comment: Thanks @StevenGreen, that was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is register the database as a DAC and you can detect drift before releasing your code. If drift is detected you can either

- Retrofit the changes made in production back into your source code
- Accept the change will be overwritten which means you need to reregister the database as a DAC and then deploy.

By having a standard deployment process from dev to prod you can use drift detection to see if someone has done something they shouldnt have and you can trust the environment hasnt changed. I wouldnt suggest doing a dacpac vs dacpac compare.